# Area 51 badges are not visible

Tags: bug, badges, profile-page, area-51

I created account in Area 51, and I also created account in other communities.

I've had 3 bronze badges there for many days.

However, under "Accounts" section of my [Activity profile tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4850591/lakhan?tab=topactivity), I see no badges for Area 51:

> [image]

Can any one tell that why it is not showing badges of Area 51?

Comment: Did you earn the badge recently? Then shouldiblamecaching.com

Comment: no i have 3 badges before so many day

Comment: Nope, I only see a "1 badge**s**" over there.

Comment: it was three and right now if it is one,then it should show right?

Comment: If you've earned the "advocate" badge recently it might just be caching. Indeed, it shows you as the most recent earner of the badge.

Comment: You have one badge on Area 51 and it's showing now. You took the screenshot two minutes after getting it, so it means the data didn't have time to synchronize yet, it's all cached to boost performance. Next time, please have some patience and wait at least one hour before assuming its a bug.

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  [Area51 badges are showing fine on mine.](http://stackexchange.com/users/2114/adam-davis?tab=accounts)

Comment: Close voters: this problem _can_ be reproduced. OP didn't realize the 3 "missing" badges were those they have on Area 51 _Discussions_.

Comment: @S.L.Barth that is guessing, nowhere in the question it's mentioned OP means Discussion Zone. Your edit also doesn't give any hint. Until OP confirms that's what he means, I'm not reopening. And the real problem was the one badge on Area 51 itself, which was caching.

Comment: @ShadowWizard If the OP isn't aware that they were on the Area 51 Discussion Zone, they could hardly mention it. I've had the same confusion about "disappearing" badges when I started on Area 51. My answer fits the observations made by the OP in the question and comments.

Comment: @S.L.Barth the same applies to any per site meta, but like I said before, that's not relevant to the actual problem described here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have [3 bronze badges](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/127387/lakhan) in Area 51 Discussions, the per-site meta of Area 51.

What is shown on your activity tab is your badges on Area 51 itself, the main site of Area 51.
At the time of asking, you had [1 bronze badge there](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/127387/lakhan), and it is shown in your profile now.
That you didn't see that single bronze badge earlier in your accounts tab, is due to caching. The accounts tab isn't updated immediately.

Comment: i think you said right..now my badge is visible